# Next.js Dynamic URL with _error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

**[id].tsx**

```
const Home:NextPage<any> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(props)}
    </div>
  )
}
Home.getInitialProps = async (props) => {
  // getting data from Database if we have an item which matched props.query.id;

  const response = await axios.get('https://MY_API.com/'+props.query.id);''
  // response format is like this
  /*
    response: {
      status: 200 | 500,
      item: Item | undefined
    }
  */
  //If response has no item, I would like to show _error.tsx instead [id].tsx
  return { ...props, response };
}
export default Home;
```

**_error.tsx**

```
const Error:NextPage<any> = (props) => {
  return <div>ERROR PAGE</div>
}
export default Error;
```

I've found one solution, it is redirecting to `/_error` but I don't want to change the `URL`.

`localhost:3000/EXIST_ID` => show **[id].tsx** and keep URL

`localhost:3000/NOT_EXIST_ID` => show **_error.tsx** and keep URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use custom server, and render the "error" page when the id is not exists.

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    const page = IS_ID_EXISTS? '/posts' : '/_error';
    return app.render(req, res, page, { id: req.params.id })
  })

  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```